# How do I change the JLabel text by clicking on my JButton?

Tags: java, awt, jbutton, jlabel

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

class myAction extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    myAction() {

        super("Lab 4 Question 1");

        Container c = getContentPane();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

        JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 3");

        Font newFont = new Font("SERIF", Font.BOLD, 16);
        b1.setFont(newFont);
        b1.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel l = new JLabel("Hello.");

        p.add(b);
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);
        p1.add(l);
        c.add(p);
        c.add(p1);

        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300, 300);
        show();
    }

    public static void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(b))
        {
            this.l.setText("Testing");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myAction output = new myAction();
    }
}
```

How do I make my JButton b1 change the value of my JLabel l ? I am fairly new to programming so I'm sorry for any mistakes that you guys notice! I just need it to change whenever I click the button, I thought I had it right but my symbols can't be found and I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to pass them into the method :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you didn't even added `ActionListener` for your button and make `actionPerformed` method as non-static (just remove `static`). This solves a problem:

```
b.addActionListener(this);
```

Also, I recommend to use anonymous inner classes instead of implementing `ActionListener` directly to your class. Like this:

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Also, make your `JButton's` vars. as instance variables (move them outside of constructor).

Comment: @DáithíCushen It's simple: `actionPerformed` cannot be a static when you implement `ActionListener`. Second, you add `ActionListener` by passing `this` keyword in `addActionListener` method of one of your buttons. And third, move those `JButton` declarations (i.e `JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");`) outside of constructor (just below: `class myAction extends JFrame implements ActionListener {`).

Answer (score 0):

`b` is not visible to your actionPerformed method because it is defined in the constructor. You need to move the variable `b` outside of `myAction()`.

```
class myAction extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton b;
    myAction() {
        b = new JButton("Click");
```

Comment: Still getting 3 errors, it still cannot find my symbol l, myAction.java:39: error: actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in myAction cannot implement actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
 public static void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { 

and 

myAction.java:40: error: non-static variable b cannot be referenced from a static context
  if(e.getSource().equals(b))